# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100813b50) fatal error

Tags: ios, swift

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate  {

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
    let soundArray = ["dog","cow","bear","pig"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func dogSound(_ sender: UIButton) {
       playSound(soundName: soundArray[sender.tag - 1])
    }

    func playSound (soundName : String) {
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:soundName, withExtension: "wav")
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:  soundURL!)
        }

        catch  {
            print(error)
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

You can see the image below I have a problem with unwrapping. I am new to the Swift language, and this is the 3rd day, I am trying to solve this problem but I can't find the solution. Can you help me and tell how to fix this nil thing? Cheers

[fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYjoQ.png)

Comment: The sound file in the application bundle does not exist. And don't post screen shots, post code (text)

Comment: did you added dog.wav or your array name.wav file in your project ?

Comment: Hi, yes i did put all sound files in my project. I am trying to practice with sounds, but this kiling me right now.

Comment: sound file name and extension are same as written in code. double verify with name and its extension

Comment: Is the `Target Membership` checkbox checked for the appropriate target?

Answer (score 0):

Reason for error : The sound file being used doesn't exist in the project. Please check either the names or the extension(.wav, .mp3) of the sound files.

Detail description : 
This error occurs when the value you are using doesn't exist, in your case the sound file that you are trying to use by passing names in the array doesn't exist.

Possible reasons :-
1) The sound file that you are using doesn't exists in the project
2) There is some name or extension(.wav, .mp3) mismatch of the sound file in the project and their name being used in code.

Debugging issue :- 
1) Try print the name of the sound file (soundArray[sender.tag - 1]) as 1st line in

func playSound (soundName : String) {

}